# Is it useful to run database in a container cluster (for horizontal scalability)?

Tags: sql, database, architecture, containers, nosql

I have to build a little cloud with several web application, which is scaleable. For an application there are several solutions such kubernetes or docker swarm etc.

For the SQL database it is not easy to make the right choice, because it seems you can not increase the performance by adding a new cluster node (or is it?).

I searched some solution (example: [crate.io](https://crate.io)). Has anyone experienced with it? Or is the best solution, to use NoSQL databases? Has anyone an idea, which infrastructure is a good solution to centralize the database in the cluster and nevertheless has the option of **horizontal** scalibility?

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any experience with crate.io, but there are several NoSQL databases that allow you to horizontally scale the data.

I have experience using Oracle NoSQL Database, that allows you to run SQL queries on NoSQL data store and the data is organized in shared-nothing manner across multiple storage nodes, you can grow and shrink your cluster by adding and removing storage nodes - horizontal scalability.

You can get more details here - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/nosqldb/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is really an option. Do you know if it is possible to run it in a container like docker for clustering in a system like kubernetes?

Comment: It is certainly possible. I dont have any cookbook for this particular set up though. I can work with you if you need help.